# How to retrieve the date from the database in a proper way using Java?

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve the datetime value from my database and I have declared the upload_date_time to be Instant and this is how the value is stored in database.

[image: Database]

However, when I attempted to retrieve the value from the database it is giving me '2022-03-01T14:00:00Z'.

UploadOrder Table

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "upload_date_time", nullable = false)
private Instant uploadDateTime;

public Instant getUploadDateTime() {
    return uploadDateTime;
}

public UploadOrder uploadDateTime(Instant uploadDateTime) {
    this.uploadDateTime= uploadDateTime;
    return this;
}

public void setUploadDateTime(Instant uploadDateTime) {
    this.uploadDateTime= uploadDateTime;
}
```

Service

```
public PrePickOrderOverPickEmailDTO generateOverPickEmails() {
log.debug("Request to retrieve Upload data : {}");
List<UploadOrder> uploadOrders = uploadPickRepository.findAllByEmailSent(false);
String data = "";
for (UploadOrder order : uploadOrders) {
        data = data +
        "Upload Date: " + order.getUploadDateTime() +"\n" +
         // do others
 }
}
```

Curious to know what am I doing wrong here. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: What's the timezone setting of your database?

Comment: @Lae It is in (UTC+10:00) Brisbane.

Comment: `2022-03-02T00:00+10:00` and `2022-03-01T14:00:00Z` are the same instant, what value are you expecting to see instead?

Comment: @Lae I'm expecting to see the one from the database (22-03-02), but I'm getting is 2022-03-01. Interestingly, I tried to use `Date newDate = Date.from(order.getUploadDateTime());` and it kinda gave the right answer, but I'm not sure whether this is the correct approach.

Comment:  **What *exactly* is the data type of your column?** And confirm your database engine is *Microsoft SQL Server* as the Tag would suggest.

Comment: From what framework library is your `@Column` annotation?

Answer (score 3):

Since you commented your database timezone is UTC+10:00, then what you are seeing is correct.

`2022-03-02T00:00+10:00` is the same date as `2022-03-01T14:00:00Z`, Z is UTC(+0), so they both represent the same date value, just represented with different time zones.

You can verify this by:

```bash
jshell> java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse("2022-03-02T00:00+10:00").toInstant()
$4 ==> 2022-03-01T14:00:00Z
```

To localize the UTC instant to a different zone, you can use `Instant::atZone()` or `Instant::atOffset()`.

Answer (score -1):

An `Instant` is a moment in time, without any time zone being specified.  And the `Instant` that you're actually storing is 2pm on 1 March UTC, which is the same as midnight on 2 March AEST.

When you're looking at this value through your SQL client, the SQL client is translating it to your local time, so you're seeing midnight on 2 March.

When you're retrieving it with your Java program, you're displaying it without specifying a time zone or time offset.  When you do that to an `Instant`, you get to see it in UTC.

What you actually want to do is convert the `Instant` to a `LocalDateTime` before you display it - that way, you'll be able to see it in AEST, or whatever your local time zone happens to be.  The `LocalDateTime` class has a `static` method called `ofInstant`, which will do that.   You need to pass the `ZoneId` for your timezone, like this.

```
LocalDateTime timeInBrisbane = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(uploadDateTime, ZoneId.of("Australia/Brisbane"));
```

or even like this, to get the system default time zone.

```
LocalDateTime timeInDefaultZone = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(uploadDateTime, ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Comment: I would prefer `ZonedDateTime` over `LocalDateTime` to prevent any confusion about time zones (it seems the OP had sufficient such confusion already).

Comment: I agree with the Comment here: `LocalDateTime` adds no value here, only adds confusion.

Answer (score -1):

## Data type

The Tag on your Question indicates you are using *Microsoft SQL Server* as your database engine.

According to [the doc,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#DateandTimeDataTypes) you should be defining your  column as the data type `datetimeoffset`. That type is akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` which **stores a moment**.

Do *not* use the types `smalldatetime`, `datetime`, nor `datetime2`. These lack the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So **these cannot represent a moment**, a specific point on the time line.

Given your code snippets using the name `uploadDateTime`, your business logic requires tracking a moment. So your table column must be of type `datetimeoffset`.

Your first sentence says:

> I'm trying to retrieve the datetime value

If you mean literally, `datetime` type in Microsoft SQL Server, you are using the wrong type for your column. This will cause you confusion and trouble.

## `OffsetDateTime`

While you neglected to mention what framework library you are using with your `@Column` annotation. So I cannot say with certainty, but I can guess that `Instant` is the wrong Java class to use here.

The [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) specification for JDBC 4.2 and later requires [JDBC drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) to support the *java.time* classes. The spec maps values of the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` to the Java class `java.time.OffsetDateTime`. The Java class `Instant` is *not* mapped at all in JDBC.

After retrieving an `OffsetDateTime`, you can extract an `Instant` if needed:  `Instant instant = myOffsetDateTime.toInstant() ;`.